# MongoDB complex query for matching elements in array and performance

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver, database-performance

Say I have following data structure:

```
{
"_id" : LUUID("d14c526e-34ba-4c41-9bb0-3bc32d9de106"),
"Address" : {
    "Street" : "Winner street",
    "HouseNo" : "776",
    "PostalCode" : 9619,
    "City" : "Majestic"
},
"Sales" : {
    "Price" : 1315000,
    "Submitted" : ISODate("2013-07-31T16:30:00Z"),
    "SaleChanges" : [ 
        {
            "ChangeDate" : ISODate("2013-08-01T14:40:18Z"),
            "Price" : 1795000
        },
        {
            "ChangeDate" : ISODate("2013-08-03T14:40:18Z"),
            "Price" : 1340000
        }
    ]
}
```

}

And I need to find price decreases for "SaleChanges" for some period of time.

Now I'm using C# driver for mongodb, linq based query and some C# extensions methods:

```
internal static bool HasPriceDecreasesInLastSpan(this SaleModel sales, TimeSpan span, DateTime from)
    {
        var date = from;
        var dateSpanBefore = date.Subtract(span);
        var salesHistory = new List<PreviousSaleModel>();

        var lastSale = sales.SaleChanges.OrderByDescending(s => s.ChangeDate).FirstOrDefault();
        if (lastSale != null)
        {
            salesHistory.Add(new PreviousSaleModel()
            {
                ChangeDate = lastSale.ChangeDate,
                Price = sales.Price
            });
        }
        salesHistory.AddRange(sales.SaleChanges.Where((sc => sc.ChangeDate >= dateSpanBefore && sc.ChangeDate <= from)));

        return salesHistory.HasPriceDecreases();
    }

internal static bool HasPriceDecreases(this IEnumerable<PreviousSaleModel> salesHistory)
    {
        using (var e = salesHistory.OrderByDescending(key => key.ChangeDate).GetEnumerator())
        {
            var buffer = new List<PreviousSaleModel>();
            while (e.MoveNext())
            {
                foreach (var item in buffer)
                {
                    if (item.Price < e.Current.Price)
                        return true;
                }
                buffer.Add(e.Current);
            }
        }

        return false;
    }

var predicate = new Func<UnitModel, bool>(bm => bm.Sales != null && bm.Sales.SaleChanges.Count > 0 && bm.Sales.HasPriceDecreasesInLastNDays(days, fromDate));
        _query = _query.Where(predicate).AsQueryable();
```

Main problem with this solution is performance lost. Mongo should look inside every record to make computations. Is there alternatives to this?

Comment: You could design the database to hold extra information, such as the price difference between changes. But with the current design, you could use an inefficient query (which does not use indexes): `db.collection.find( { $where: "this.SaleChanges[1] < this.SaleChanges[0]" } );` or `db.collection.find( { $where: "this.SaleChanges[this.SaleChanges.length - 1] < this.SaleChanges[0]" } );`

Comment: You might be able to build your request using aggregation. Have you tried that? It's not nearly as nice syntactically from C#, but the performance should be far far better (assuming you can get aggregation to work).

Answer (score 0):

If you need to query on the difference between the price and salesChange.price, I'd recommend storing the computed value with each item in the array. Just set it before each insert and update. You've got a couple of options for getting computed values like that in the query but it's going to be slow any way you do it. If this is something you'll need to do often, just set it before you insert it and create an index on it.

Folks schooled in more traditional databases woud cringe at the idea of denormalizing your data willy nilly, but Mongo isn't a relational database, it's based on Documents. In general, you can feel free to denormalize data WITHIN a document because generally the entire document is always updated atomically, so there's not the same risk of ending up with invalid data.